# How to decrement elements on both sides in list

Tags: python, list

I want to get this:

```
[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['', 'A', '']]
```

I have some code, but in result I get:

```
[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'A']]
```

I understand that I just insert this char, but how to get removing element from both sides?

base - base of pyramid

char - letter which should fill pyramid

```py
def matrix(base: int, char: str) -> list:
    new_list = []
    n = 0
    for i in range(base // 2 + 1):
        row = []
        for m in range(base):
            row.insert(n, char)
            n += 1
        new_list.append(row)
    return new_list

matrix(3, "A")
```

Comment: Why did you expect that first input? You don't seem to have any conditional logic that might make that happen, and it's not clear what criteria it's supposed to be following anyway.

Comment: base - base of pyramid

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
def matrix(base: int, char: str) -> list:
    new_list = []
    step = 0
    while step < base / 2:
        row = ['']*step + [char]*(base-2*step) + ['']*step
        new_list.append(row)
        step += 1
    return new_list

matrix(3,"A")
```

Comment: For even-numbered values of the base, your method generates 1 less element in your list than @pibo's list and my list. The element with all `''` is missing.

Comment: @PrajwalDhatwalia The question does not say anything about an element with all `''`. If you are trying to represent a pyramid, this element seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below lines to the outer `for` loop in your existing code should give you the desired result:

```
for j in range(0,i):
        new_list[i][j] = ''
        new_list[i][-1-j] = ''
```

Explanation:
In every iteration, we are basically making one more element in the beginning and end of the list as `''` than before.

So, the resulting code will be:

```
def matrix(base: int, char: str) -> list:
    new_list = []
    n = 0
    for i in range(base // 2 + 1):
        row = []
        for m in range(base):
            row.insert(n, char)
            n += 1
        new_list.append(row)

        for j in range(0,i):
            new_list[i][j] = ''
            new_list[i][-1-j] = ''

    return new_list

print(matrix(3,"A"))
```